# Can you recover deleted rows from an h2 database table?

Tags: h2

I have an h2 database where a user has accidently deleted some data from a table.

The database is not corrupted, and if I open and close the database, the file size compacts from ~600Mb to ~400Mb. Is there a way to recover any deleted records? I can run the recovery tool but obviously this discards the deleted data.

The database is from h2 1.3.76 as an h2.db file.